# Lazy loading (one to one using FK) issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence

when executing session.createQuery("from Author").list();
The associated book instance info is loaded eagerly even when relationship is marked  optional=false,fetch type = lazy from Author->book as per below generated sql's.
I have this relationship as one to one just for understanding purposes, and not one to many at the moment. Is it possible to make it lazy from Author-Book, if so not sure what I am missing?

Hibernate: select author0_.AUTHOR_ID as AUTHOR_I1_0_, author0_.email as email2_0_, author0_.name as name3_0_ from AUTHOR author0_

Hibernate: select book0_.BOOK_ID as BOOK_ID1_1_0_, book0_.AUTHOR_ID as AUTHOR_I5_1_0_, book0_.description as descript2_1_0_, book0_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE3_1_0_, book0_.title as title4_1_0_ from BOOK book0_ where book0_.AUTHOR_ID=?

Hibernate: select book0_.BOOK_ID as BOOK_ID1_1_0_, book0_.AUTHOR_ID as AUTHOR_I5_1_0_, book0_.description as descript2_1_0_, book0_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE3_1_0_, book0_.title as title4_1_0_ from BOOK book0_ where book0_.AUTHOR_ID=?

Hibernate: select book0_.BOOK_ID as BOOK_ID1_1_0_, book0_.AUTHOR_ID as AUTHOR_I5_1_0_, book0_.description as descript2_1_0_, book0_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE3_1_0_, book0_.title as title4_1_0_ from BOOK book0_ where book0_.AUTHOR_ID=?

Hibernate: select book0_.BOOK_ID as BOOK_ID1_1_0_, book0_.AUTHOR_ID as AUTHOR_I5_1_0_, book0_.description as descript2_1_0_, book0_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE3_1_0_, book0_.title as title4_1_0_ from BOOK book0_ where book0_.AUTHOR_ID=?

Hibernate: select book0_.BOOK_ID as BOOK_ID1_1_0_, book0_.AUTHOR_ID as AUTHOR_I5_1_0_, book0_.description as descript2_1_0_, book0_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE3_1_0_, book0_.title as title4_1_0_ from BOOK book0_ where book0_.AUTHOR_ID=?

Hibernate: select book0_.BOOK_ID as BOOK_ID1_1_0_, book0_.AUTHOR_ID as AUTHOR_I5_1_0_, book0_.description as descript2_1_0_, book0_.PUBLISHED as PUBLISHE3_1_0_, book0_.title as title4_1_0_ from BOOK book0_ where book0_.AUTHOR_ID=?

```
@Entity
@BatchSize(size=3)
@Table(name = "AUTHOR")
public class Author {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Book book;


    public Author() {
    }

    public Author(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "AUTHOR_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional=false,mappedBy="author")
    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }


@Entity
@BatchSize(size=3)
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {

     private long id;
        private String title;
        private String description;
        private Date publishedDate;

        private Author author;

        public Book() {
        }

        @Id
        @Column(name = "BOOK_ID")
        @GeneratedValue
        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name = "PUBLISHED")
        public Date getPublishedDate() {
            return publishedDate;
        }

        public void setPublishedDate(Date publishedDate) {
            this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
        }

        @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional=false)
        @JoinColumn(name ="AUTHOR_ID",unique=true)
        public Author getAuthor() {
            return author;
        }

        public void setAuthor(Author author) {
            this.author = author;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing that the link from `Author` to `Book` isn't the definition owner of the bidirectional association, I mean it is defined as mappedBy and the FK resides in the `Book` table.
So when an Author is retrieved, it needs to query over the Book table to check the FK and find out if there is a book and which book is associated per Author. That is why you are seeing as many select statement on book table as Authors you have (it is known as the *N+1 Query Problem*).

One way to avoid it is switch the owner side of the association (defining in Author table a FK to the Book) but you will see analogous behavior quering for books.

If your concern are the collateral queries, one option is apply a fetching strategy in the query forcing to retrieve the Books associated with the Authors. The query will be something like,
`session.createQuery("from Author a left join fetch a.book").list();`

I told you the cause and basic solution/workaround but there are more complicated options too, you could find those in stackoverflow for sure.