# JPA 2 - INNER JOIN calls Query again

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to do some query in JPA 2 but it keeps calling another query to get informatinos of a dependency

My Classes are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbltranslados")
public class Traslado implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(optional = true, mappedBy = "traslado", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private TrasladoHora hora;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbltranshora")
public class TrasladoHora implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(optional = false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "thr_TransladosID")
    private Traslado traslado;
}
```

I call the query like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Traslado> listarAtivos() {
    return this.session.createQuery("SELECT t , h FROM Traslado t LEFT JOIN t.hora h WHERE t.status=:status ORDER BY t.origem , t.destino")
            .setParameter("status", true)
            .getResultList();
}
```

But my result is:

> Hibernate: select traslado0_.TransladosID as Translad1_14_0_, trasladoho1_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_1_, traslado0_.tra_Para as tra_Para2_14_0_, traslado0_.tra_De as tra_De3_14_0_, traslado0_.tra_Status as tra_Stat4_14_0_, trasladoho1_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_1_, trasladoho1_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_1_ from tbltranslados traslado0_ left outer join tbltranshora trasladoho1_ on traslado0_.TransladosID=trasladoho1_.thr_TransladosID where traslado0_.tra_Status=? order by traslado0_.tra_De, traslado0_.tra_Para
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?
>   Hibernate: select trasladoho0_.TranshoraID as Transhor1_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_qtdHoras as thr_qtdH2_13_0_, trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID as thr_Tran3_13_0_ from tbltranshora trasladoho0_ where trasladoho0_.thr_TransladosID=?

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the *select n+1 problem*.

The first query that you get retrieves the list you want but in order to instance the objects of entity `Traslado`, Hibernate invoke one select statement per object to find out if it has a `TrasladoHora` associated because the relationship is mapped in the `TrasladoHora`'s table (I mean that `TrasladoHora.traslado` is the owner side of this bi-directional association).

[Here is a answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/97253/1676564) commented by a lot of people with suggestions but the problem and some workaround is mention in Hibernate documentation in section [Tuning fetch strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-custom)

Edit: [I also respond another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31227335/1676564) related to this problem, perhaps you find a more clear explanation there.